# Why are iphones pushing content outside of the viewport?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, viewport

My website should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E7Ic.jpg), and does so on android devices etc. I am having some trouble with the iphone, having tested it on a few of them, it appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECbNY.jpg)?

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue? For your reference, its www.teamthie.com and here is the relevant code:

```
.slide {position: relative;
padding-top: 0px;
height: 100vh;
-webkit-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: Fjalla One;
}
.heading {
width: 45%;
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
right: 5%;
color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
font-weight: 700;
text-align: right;
z-index: 10;
text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor: default;
}
.heading-date{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 17px;
}
.heading-big {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 52px;
}
.heading-small {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: Fjalla One;
}
.heading-small a {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 700;
color: #60CAFE;
}
```

Comment: Flagging for: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.* You can [edit] your question to add a code sample or (preferably) a code snippet with enough HTML/CSS to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just an fyi posting your code would be helpful but you could try this 1) changing display: inline-block; to display: inline-table; (or table) sometimes fixes positioning problems.

Here some info about viewports that I used for the iPhone http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone and [more info](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)

You can also define the viewport within CSS instead of using the meta tag. Check the more info link.

Comment: ha just beat me to it before i edited the post to include the code. Currently reading through your links, thanks.

Comment: No problem I hope it helps :)